# how to create expandable listview with cursortreeadapter?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new to android development and I am developing android application from scratch now I want to implement custom expandable listview which will have edit text in parent and child also edit text and toggle button can anyone suggest me some suitable tutorial for it or suggest me how do I implement this ?
Thanks in advance . I did lot of googling but I didn't get

Comment: Why do you need CursorTreeAdapter?

Comment: Why not with BaseExpandableAdapter???

Comment: I thing using CursorTreeAdapter I could implement what objective on I need to do